# .NET working directory of loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net

in a C# application i load another application via

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("tool.dll");
```

and then run it via

```
Type typeGame = assembly.GetType("com.Program");
object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeGame);
typeGame.InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instanceOfMyType, null);
```

this loaded application loads files from its current working directory, which works fine when run alone.

but when it is loaded into another application like above it gives FileNotFoundExceptions, even though the working directory is correct and the file is there.

also if i output the working directory via

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

it tells me the correct directory where the file resides.

Comment: Did you try sending full path something like this? Assembly.LoadFrom(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +@"\tool.dll")?

Comment: Do I understand that the new Assembly you are loading is trying to load files on its own but is unable to as it get the new relative path of the main Application, but not the relative path of its own?

Comment: @sgud the assembly itself loads fine, its files that this assembly loads which is failing.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras yes, actually both assemblies use the same working directory. the loaded assembly then loads a txt-file which is also in this directory but it fails doing so.

Comment: Ah! They reside in the same directory? Then I guess I have no ideas.

Comment: @clamp AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory??

Comment: Start up the "FusLogVw.exe" tool (admin mode if running on UAC enabled windows). Change the settings to "Log all bind failures". Run your program, refresh the fus(ion)logv(ie)w(er) window and find your program entry. View the log. This will show you where the fusion engine (CLR assembly loader) tried to load your assembly from.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` method and check whether you have it loaded into your domain or not. Generally, all dlls in the bin folder (execution folder) are loaded into the domain assemblies list. At least that is true for asp.net web applications.

Comment: interestingly this returns indeed another directory. how could this happen?

Comment: no it doesn't return another directory, it returns the loaded assemblies in the current domain of the application. There are different ways to load an assembly to your application. The suggested approach is to create your own domain and then load your custom assembly in that domain. But here as I understood your case is that the dll is in the same directory as the exe file is. So you should be able to find your assembly file in current domain loaded assemblies